# Is there is any way to find the parameters required for WhatsApp business API dynamically

Tags: reactjs, whatsapp

Is there any way to find out the number of parameter and the parameter name required by a WhatsApp business API dynamically. I don't know which API the user will choose but I want to know all the parameters required by that choice of the user.

I couldn't think of any solutions myself